# Is it acceptable to leave the javamail session Transport open?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

My application needs to send emails on an ad hoc basis.  I'm using javamail's getDefaultSession and getTransport to send the message, and it's all working as expected.

However I've noticed that the send can take a long time - up to seven seconds per send.  If I break the steps down, like this:

```
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect();
transport.sendMessage( msg, addresses )
transport.close();
```

...I can see that it's the connect() call that takes almost all of the time, each time.

All of the examples I've found do this - get a transport, connect, send, disconnect.  But of course they're all single-shot examples, or sending large batches of emails in a single call.

I was thinking I could just leave the connection open, like this:

```
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
if (!transport.isConnected())
    transport.connect();
transport.sendMessage( msg, addresses )
```

(There's a variation on that, here: [java mail keeping Transport object connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358569/java-mail-keeping-transport-object-connected)).

I'll have to close it eventually, in a shutdown hook of some kind.  And I might have to have a fallback (if the connection has been lost but the transport doesn't realise).  But is there any reason not to just leave it open like this during the application lifetime?

Thanks,
Alastair

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't really see any problem in keeping a single SMTP connection open, and the use of Transport Object is recommended for connection reuse (see the [JavaMail tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html#JavaMailTransport)).

Additionally, I would recommend you to keep just one smpt connection (through Transport) open at your application, keeping it at a single manager instance (i.e using a singleton pattern), avoiding the eventual cost of keeping a different connection open for every component which needs send a message.

Comment: Hi Tomas, thanks for that - exactly what I was hoping.  I am indeed planning on using it within a singleton 'EmailSender' instance, so this should be fine.

Comment: This approach could lead to severe performance issues in multi-threaded environment as outlined in my answer

Answer (score 4):

As per `@Bill Shannon`'s (author of JavaMail) answer here:
[Threadsafety in Javamail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732584/threadsafety-in-javamail#answer-12733317)

> Since a Transport represents a connection to a mail server, and only a single thread can use the connection at a time, a Transport will synchronize access from multiple threads to maintain thread safety, but you'll really only want to use it from a single thread.

So if you plan to use single `Transport` instance from **multiple threads** (which is usually the case nowadays), it's actually quite **bad idea** from **performance point of view**. You'll probably better off developing some sort of pool of `Transport` instances using `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: Should someone need code example of such pool - please leave a comment here and I'll expand my answer with it

Comment: Hello Yura, I am interested in some example, actually I developed a code whit problems for read mails whit imap from multiple thread, I have the session in a singleton ejb but the other code for access to mail information is in stateless ejb. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Gaalvarez this might help you, just set the pool size to 1 if you really want that: https://github.com/nithril/smtp-connection-pool