# Threadsafety in Javamail

Tags: java, multithreading, smtp, jakarta-mail

I'm researching whether Javamail is threadsafe, in particular in a situation with many sessions corresponding to different users, several SMTP servers and the use of creating MIME messages and use of `transport.sendMessage` method.  I know Javamail is oriented toward desktop-use which makes me suspect it may not have been built with threading in mind, and am wondering if anyone has such experience.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Admittedly the thread safety rules for JavaMail are not well documented, but hopefully they mostly match what you would expect.

Multiple threads can use a Session.

Since a Transport represents a connection to a mail server, and only a single thread can use the connection at a time, a Transport will synchronize access from multiple threads to maintain thread safety, but you'll really only want to use it from a single thread.

Similarly, a Store can be used by multiple threads, but access to the underlying connection will be synchronized and single threaded.

A Message should only be modified by a single thread at a time, but multiple threads should be able to read a message safely (although it's not clear why you would want to do that).

Comment: Did you learn this from the javadoc, the sources, of from experience?

Comment: Kudos! Since there were no references backing your explanations, I was wondering how you could be so assertive. Now I understand ;) Clearly, +1 !

Comment: It's very nice that you answer so many JavaMail questions without caring much for reputation. You're a real Unsung Hero!

Comment: @BillShannon - Does that mean that copying messages from one Store to another with multiple threads will have no performance benefit over doing so in a single thread?  Thanks!

Comment: It depends.  Each open folder uses a single connection, and operations on the connection are single threaded by necessity.  You can open the folder multiple times; whether that will help will depend on the server.  And certainly if you're operating on multiple folders it will likely help to use multiple threads.

Comment: @BillShannon, can you confirm this answer is still up-to-date 7 years later? I'm maintaining a JavaMail SMTP wrapper library called [SimpleJavaMail](https://github.com/bbottema/simple-java-mail) and we're having a discussion on multi-threading and performance over [here](https://github.com/bbottema/simple-java-mail/issues/198).

Comment: @BennyBottema Yes, the threading model hasn't changed.  Obviously the choice of multiple threads and multiple connections will depend on the cpu and network performance of the client and server, and any other connection or throughput limitations the server may impose.

Answer (score 2):

The javamail dispatcher threads doesn't seem to timeout if the server doesn't respond in time. this leads to locking on all available threads.

Tested this behavior with both 1.4.3 & 1.4.5.