# spring mvc prototype vs locks/synchronization

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, jakarta-mail

I have a user registration controller:

```
@Autowired
private EmailTools emailTools;


@Controller
public class RegistrationController {

@RequestMapping(value="/registerUser", method=RequestMethod.POST )
public String registerUser(HttpSession session,Model model,User user){
//RegisterUserDetails of scope prototype
RegisterUserDetails regUserDetails = 
appContext.getBean(RegisterUserDetails.class);
//rgistering user in db
regUserDetails.setUser(user);
//sending confirmation email  
emailTools.SendEmail(user.getEmail(), subject, content);
return "home";
```

}

The emailTools class:

```
public class EmailTools {
private Properties props;
private Key internalKey;
public EmailTools(Properties props, Key internalKey){
    this.props=props;
    this.internalKey=internalKey;

}

public synchronized void SendEmail(String toAddress, String subject, String content) {


    final String fromAddress = props.getProperty("from.address");
    final String password = Encryptor.decrypt(props.getProperty("email.password"),internalKey);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(fromAddress, password);
        }
      });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse(toAddress));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(content);
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

At present the emailTools class is a singleton. I have put a synchronised block around the sendEmail method to make it thread safe?

1) Is the current method thread safe?
2) If so, is it better to make the scope of emailTools a prototpe/request/session or a singleton that uses synchronization? Which is better?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Threadsafety in Javamail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732584/threadsafety-in-javamail) , all `Session`- and `Transport`-related operations are thread-safe.

So if your `Encryptor.decrypt()` is thread-safe, then `SendEmail()` is thread-safe too and no synchronization is needed.

But it is not clear whether `registerUser()` is thread-safe. If `RegisterUserDetails` is a singleton AND `setUser()` is actually a setter that modifies some shared state (and not a method that just saves something to database), AND that shared state (user?) is used (indirectly) by `SendEmail()` (for instance, in `Encryptor.decrypt()`), then the whole construct may be not thread-safe.